# A query where one "and" condition doesn't always apply

Tags: sql, sql-server

I basically want to create an "if" function in a SQL query.  Here is the query:

```
SELECT sum(amount), count(*) 
FROM Facilities 
    WHERE date = @Date 
    and system = 'LNI' 
    and entity is not NULL 
    and amount > 0
    and cust_cd != 'M' 
    and default_status = 'ACC' 
    and product_code NOT IN ('A', 'B', 'C')

    and expiration_date >= @Date
```

The last condition only applies to some of the rows captured in this query.

What I want to dream up into existence is something like:

```
   and (product_code IN ('D', 'E')
      and expiration_date >= @Date )
 +
   and ( product_code IN ('F', 'G')
     and expiration_date = expiration_date)
```

I hope I am explaining my question correctly. Is there a way to make an "and" condition conditional on other factors, or do I have to separate this into two nearly identical queries?

Comment: what does `expiration_date = expiration_date` mean? Is that an esoteric way to make sure `expiration_date is not null`?

Comment: @SqlZim Good Q at good point

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
AND (
        (product_code IN ('D', 'E') AND expiration_date >= @Date)
     OR (product_code IN ('F', 'G') AND expiration_date = @Date)
     OR (product_code NOT IN ('D', 'E', 'F', 'G') OR product_code IS NULL) -- This line will make sure you get the rest. If all you want is the D/E and F/G conditions, remove this.
    )
```

This is probably the best way to do it. Of course things get a bit hairier if `@Date` can be NULL. These sort of 'catch-all' queries are notoriously difficult.

Comment: On the bright side, `date = @Date` seems to indicate that `@Date` wont' be `null`.

Comment: ...And then I pressed enter too soon. Stand by.

Comment: @SqlZim, sharp.

Comment: So, I want to capture the sum of all of the rows - except accounts that are a certain type AND have the expiration date condition. So my final answer should be sum of all accounts of type A that meet all of the other conditions, plus the sum of all accounts of type B that meet all of the other conditions and the condition on expiration date.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative

```
AND ( CASE 
   WHEN product_code IN ('D', 'E') THEN expiration_date >= @Date 
   WHEN product_code IN ('F', 'G') THEN expiration_date = @Date
   ELSE TRUE 
END )
```

This avoids having to synthesize the final lack of condition (@HoneyBadger's `product_code NOT IN ('D', 'E', 'F', 'G') OR product_code IS NULL`)